# Activate MFA on a single site collection in SP O365

Tags: sharepoint-online, office-365, authentication

I've taken over as 'Admin' of an online SharePoint site in Office 365 with no background in SP administration. It's been requested that we enable multi-factor authentication (MFA) for only one site collection within our site. Does anyone know if this is possible, and if so, can you point me towards documentation on how to set it up?
Based on my research, it is only possible to activate MFA per user for the whole O365 instance. https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/36857.sharepoint-online-o365-set-up-multi-factor-authentication.aspx

Comment: you can't do MFA on a single site collection. Only on the tenant or MS account itself

Comment: @Colbs please put this as an answer as it is the correct answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't set Multi Factor Authentication per Site Collection, only on the tenant or the Microsoft account itself

Here is a technet article describing the process:

https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/36857.sharepoint-online-o365-set-up-multi-factor-authentication.aspx

Comment: This answer was valid in the past, but that is no longer the case. This feature is in public preview now. You need to create a new context and assign that context to CA policy (CA needs as well user assignment so dynamic group can be used to encompass all users). Then you can assign context to an site using this pnp Set-SPOSite -Identity https://yourTenant.sharepoint.com/sites/siteName -ConditionalAccessPolicy AuthenticationContext -AuthenticationContextName "MFA_ON_SPO"

Answer (score 0):

Actually, with some customization, it is possible o have a single site OR just a library enforce MFA.  We had that done for our Sharepoint online install.  I am not the technologist to ask on "how", but it certainly is possible

Answer (score 0):

It is possible (if you have Azure premium license) to set up MFA requirement for one specific site. We did it this way.

1. Set up an context
2. Set up an Conditional access policy that is using the context and have following groups.

   Include: AllTenantMembers (dynamic)

   Exclude: SP-ServiceAccount (Assigned Membership)
3. Assign context to the site running this command.

   Set-SPOSite -Identity https://yourTenant.sharepoint.com/sites/siteName -ConditionalAccessPolicy AuthenticationContext -AuthenticationContextName "MFA_ON_SPO"